# Mysql query to count number of days of login

Tags: mysql, sql

It is common to count the number of days that users login to the system (like stackexchange). In an ordinary user table, I update login information as

```
UPDATE users SET 
last_login='date', number_of_login=number_of_login + 1, number_of_days=? 
WHERE user_id='user_id'
```

where last_date is `datetime`

what is the best to check that current day is different from `last_login` to update number of days with `number_of_day=number_of_day+1`.

I have two methods in mind, but they seems to be naive:

Method 1: having a `SELECT` to catch last_login and compare it with current day in PHP

Method 2: using a trick like sub-SELECT

I hope to do this with one simple query (if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I don't get your comment wrong, you want to always update last_login, but number_of_days only if last_login != curdate(). Try this:

```
UPDATE users SET 
number_of_days = if (last_login = curdate(), number_of_days, number_of_days + 1),
last_login='date', number_of_login = number_of_login + 1
WHERE user_id='user_id'
```

Comment: the WHERE clause will stop the whole update; but we need to record last_login in any case (whether this is the first login of today or several times)

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer. Let me know if this time I got it right :)

Answer (score 2):

I would use `DATEDIFF` `MySql` function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff.

> DATEDIFF() returns expr1 – expr2 expressed **as a value in days** from one
>   date to the other. expr1 and expr2 are date or date-and-time
>   expressions. Only the date parts of the values are used in the
>   calculation.

After you fetch results, you should check if fetched column is greater than zero to determine if dates are different.